# Widget class that implements the Comparable interface that compares to method

Tags: java, class, methods, widget, implements

I'm assuming the existence of a Widget class that implements the Comparable interface and thus has a compareTo **method** that accepts an Object parameter and returns an int. I want to Write an efficient static method, getWidgetMatch, that has two parameters. 
The first parameter is a reference to a Widget object. 
The second parameter is a potentially very large array of Widget objects that has been sorted in ascending order based on the Widget **compareTo** method. The getWidgetMatch searches for an element in the array that matches the first parameter on the basis of the equals method and returns true if found and false otherwise.

I will share two code I have almost working and my errors from debugging. Hopefully, someone has an answering I am not seeing.

Code 1:

```
public static boolean getWidgetMatch(Widget a, Widget[] b){
    int bot=0;
    int top=b.length-1;
    int x = 0;
    int y=0;
    while (bot >= top)
    {
        x = (top + bot/2);

        y = a.compareTo(b[x]);

        if (y==0) 
                return true;

        if (y<0) 
            top=x;

        else 
            bot=x;
        return false;
        }

    return a.equals(b[x]);
}
```

The debug statement for this one is this, [LWidget;@5305068a
→
false when it should be true. Am I miss a ">" sign possibly?

Code 2:

```
public static boolean getWidgetMatch(Widget a, Widget[] b) {
    for(int i =0;i<b.length;i++){
        if(b[i].compareTo(a)== 0)return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The debug statement for this one is this, 
[LWidget;@5305068a → true when it should be true and that is where I am most confused with this code.

Am I miss a "+" or "-" or a "/" sign possibly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static boolean getWidgetMatch(Widget object, Widget[] wList){
    int low = 0;
    int high = wList.length - 1;

    while(low <= high){
        int middle = low + (high-low)/2;

        if(object.compareTo(wList[middle]) < 0)
            high = middle - 1;

        else if(object.compareTo(wList[middle]) > 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```